# Cannot open `xfce4-terminal --preferences` anymore

Tags: fedora, xfce, settings, xfce4-terminal

On my Fedora 38 I'm experiencing a very weird error that emerged pretty much out of the blue.
I'm using XFCE as my desktop environment, and `xfce4-terminal` as my terminal emulator.

I noticed, that when I try to open up the preferences dialog, all open terminal sessions freeze and only after a couple seconds (~30 or so), they un-freeze, but the preferences dialog isn't opened.

I tried running `xfce4-terminal --preferences` from gnome-terminal but it still won't open a window with preferences. Instead, after a couple seconds (around 30 or so), I see the following message:

```
(xfce4-terminal:6356): GVFS-WARNING **: 10:52:06.998: The peer-to-peer connection failed: Timeout was reached. Falling back to the session bus. Your application is probably missing --filesystem=xdg-run/gvfsd privileges.
```

The preferences dialog isn't opened that way either.

I checked permissions of `~/.config/xfce4/terminal` and the files inside that directory, but it all seems fine, I'm unsure where to look next for a solution.

I can open the preferences of gnome-terminal and sakura (another terminal emulator) just fine, it's only xfce4-terminal that seems to have problems opening up the settings window.

Any hints greatly appreciated!

---

I noticed, the preferences window will open when I run it as root:
`sudo xfce4-terminal --preferences` opens up the preferences window just fine, so perhaps it's some sort of permissions error?